# Помогите понять в чём ошибка в коде (Python)

Tags: python, обработка-ошибок

Прохожу курс на Stepik, там такая задача

> Напишите программу, которая принимает на вход список чисел в одной
> строке и выводит на экран в одну строку значения, которые встречаются
> в нём более одного раза.
>
> Для решения задачи может пригодиться метод sort списка.
>
> Выводимые числа не должны повторяться, порядок их вывода может быть
> произвольным.

Мой код:

```
a = [int(i) for i in input()]
q = len(a)-1
c = []

a.sort()


for di in a:
    b = a.count(di)
    if b >= 2 and di not in c:
        c.append(di)
    continue

print(" ".join(map(str,  c)))
```

В IDE всё работает нормально, но на степик мне выдаёт ошибку:

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 1, in <module>
    a = [int(i) for i in input()]
  File "jailed_code", line 1, in <listcomp>
    a = [int(i) for i in input()]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
```

Объясните, что у меня не так, пожалуйста

Comment: для начала у вас "не так"  - разные строки. В вашем коде и в жалобе Stepik разное количество скобок. Проверяйте, что вы в Stepik скопировали.

Comment: Да, это я ковырялся. Скопировал в stepik указанный тут код, ошибка изменилась немного 
(отредактировал ошибку в вопросе)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая команда

```
a = [int(i) for i in input()]
```

должна быть

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Когда например у вас на вводе появится такой список чисел:

```
13 2 7 2
```

то функция `input()` возвращает **не список**, а просто *строку*

```
"13 2 7 2"
```

которая в генераторе списка

```
[int(i) for i in input()]
```

итерируется **по отдельным символам** — т.е. переменная `i` принимает постепенно значения `"1"`, `"3"`, `" "` - и вот ошибка

> ```
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
> ```

Пробель невозможно функцией `int()` перевести в число!

С другой стороны, из вводимой строки возможно получить желательный список `["13", "2", "7", "2"]` методом `split()`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! 
Разобрался

Comment: Не стоит, я рад, что помогло. :-)